# How do I execute a method asynchronously?

Tags: f#, task-parallel-library

The following *Instance* method takes a significant amount of time to execute.

```
module CachedTags =

    let private x = [1..25] |> List.collect getTags
    let Instance() = x
```

Thus, I would like to make this call asynchronous when initializing a server session.

As a result I thought I could take the following:

```
CachedTags.Instance() |> ignore
```

And write it like this:

```
Tasks.Task.Run(fun _ -> CachedTags.Instance() |> ignore) |> ignore
```

I'm clueless if I'm doing this correctly.
What's the recommended technique for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this tutorial](https://sachabarbs.wordpress.com/2014/05/15/f-28-integrating-with-task-parallel-library/), you can try this:

```
module CachedTags =

    // analog of task in C#
    let private x = async {
        [1..25] |> List.collect getTags
    } |> Async.StartAsTask
```

And when you need the result, you can use [different options](http://tomasp.net/blog/csharp-async-gotchas.aspx/):

```
// synchronously wait in current thread
x.Wait()
// use system class in current thread
x |> Async.RunSynchronously 
// await result
let! result = Async.AwaitTask(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Scott, just want to offer an alternative. If you're okay with instantiating your tags list on first access (rather than on module initialization, which you appear to be avoiding) you might try a lazy computation.

```
module CachedTags =

    let private x = lazy ([1..25] |> List.collect getTags)
    let Instance() = x.Value

let tags = CachedTags.Instance()
```

The use of `lazy` is fairly idiomatic, and instantiates your expression only on the first call to `Instance()` (that is, the first evaluation of `x.Value`).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/lazy-computations